# Set a limit on how many items can be used in a link list in c

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, free

I'm trying to figure out how to limit the number of items in a linked list to 5 from an array of 20, any ideas would be great.

Comment: You could have a `struct` which has one member pointing to the head of the linked list and another member indicating the number of nodes. When adding a node, check this counter, then add. When deleting, decrement this counter.

Comment: I'm kind of new to c and I'm not sure I fully understand what you are saying. Do you know of any resources or example I could look at that are beginner friendly? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: The answers illustrate what I wanted to say. You might find the answers helpful.

Comment: I've looked over both answers and tried to incorporate some of the ideas in them into my code but it still isn't working.

Comment: These are the errors that I'm running and I was using the first code as a basis:                      main.c:27:1: error: unknown type name ‘queue’
 queue *queue_create(void) {
main.c:27:1: note: use ‘struct’ keyword to refer to the type
main.c: In function ‘queue_create’:
main.c:29:29: error: ‘queue’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     return calloc(1, sizeof(queue));
main.c:29:29: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c: At top level:
main.c:79:13: error: unknown type name ‘queue’
 bool insert(queue *list, int *data)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? The biggest benefit of a linked list is that it's NOT limited. If you want to have a limit, why not just use an array?

Comment: I am given a code with a linked list and my job is to limit it to five of the values from an array. I'm supposed to leave the main code how it is and just make sure when the linked list has five variables in it, it wont allow anymore. If that doesn't make sense I can try and word it another way.

Comment: Are there multiple threads using the list, (imma guessing no, but it should be asked:)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by a list with multiple threads

Comment: there is a char array with 20 different options and i already have the code for a linked list completed I just need to be able to limit it to 5 but it keeps going infinitely currently

Answer (score 2):

You need a container storing the size of the list, something like:

```
struct node
{
    the data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    size_t size;
} queue;

queue *queue_create(void)
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof(queue));
}
```

Now your insert function can return `NULL` or false when the list is full:

```
bool insert(queue *list, the *data)
{
    if (list->size == 5)
    {
        return false;
    }

    struct node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);

    if (node == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;
    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        list->head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        list->tail->next = node;
    }
    list->tail = node;
    list->size++;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ha, ha - nearly identical answers at the same time ;-)

Comment: @4386427 yeah, there are not many alternatives :)

Comment: Im not sure how to work something like this into my code properly, I have been trying but it is producing three errors that i mentioned above. If you have an idea to fix them please let me know.

Comment: Please, update your question with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Well, an alternative is a semaphore initialized to 5 units.  Any user who wants to add an item has to get a unit first and release the unit when done.  Yes, such a queue would need a mutex as well to prevent multiple access.

Comment: @MartinJames oh yes, of course, but OP must confirm that the list is updated in a multithreaded environment first, otherwise we are going to confuse him even more :)

Comment: I dont believe i'm using a multithreaded enviorment

Comment: also what is the benefit in using bool, I'm trying to understand the code and even after looking up the function I am still confused

Comment: `insert` can fail allocating memory with `malloc`, in this case the function caller must be informed, and in your case it is also good to inform the caller that the list is full.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in so many different ways. The best solution depends on your program, i.e. how the list is used in your program.

One way is like:

```
// This struct is used for the individual nodes in the list
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
} node;

// This struct is used for managing the list - includes a size counter
typedef struct node_list {
    struct node * head;
    struct node * tail;  // optional
    size_t size;
} node_list;

#define MAX_SIZE 10

int insert(node_list * l, int data)
{
    if (l->size == MAX_SIZE)
    {
        // List is full
        return -1;
    }
    
    // Add code to insert the new node
    
    l->size = l->size + 1; // Increase size
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    node_list list = {NULL, NULL, 0}; // Create empty list

    if (insert(&list, 42) != 0)
    {
        // Insert failed - list is full
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Like the `insert` function increases `size`, you need a `delete` function where you decrease `size` when a node is deleted.